# number_format gives wrong output while using DECIMAL_POINT as constatnt for decimals parameter

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have defined constant in codeigniter constants.php file.

```
defined('DECIMAL_POINT') or define('DECIMAL_POINT','2');
```

And using it to format number as below example.

```
$number=1000000;
$amount = number_format($number,DECIMAL_POINT, '.', '');
echo $amount;
```

Output is:
1000000.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The output should be 1000000.00;

It was working fine before I updated my `PHP version to 8.2.8`

Comment: I can confirm that this seems to happen in PHP 8.2.0 but not in earlier versions. See: https://3v4l.org/F6dZ8#v8.2.0

Comment: https://3v4l.org/SihPP - looks like `DECIMAL_POINT` did not actually exist before 8.2.0, and now that it does, it has the value 65536 for some reason.

Comment: @CBroe Ah, yes, that explains it. I don't like the conditional `define()` anyway, just define something. At least you get [a clear warning](https://3v4l.org/CisG8#v8.2.8) when you do that.

Comment: @CBroe: This nl_langinfo() function entry mentions it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl-langinfo.php , I'm missing to see where the constant itself is documented as in _predefined constants_.

Comment: *“in codeigniter constants.php file”* Is it a file from Code Igniter? It doesn't appear in the project: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Abcit-ci%20DECIMAL_POINT&type=code

Comment: @A.L. Yes. it's a file from CodeIgniter. You can find it in config folder of application.

Comment: It looks like `DECIMAL_POINT` was added here: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a4fd2609ce0c9ce7bf3d13f0a111a04e3ba6f4c8#diff-96c05a0551ccbeca3ff610c111f88b54a0d727888cf353f477ea8dc951a18637R1424 But GitHub shows that it's only for PHP 8.3+

Comment: @Priya are you sure that you didn't add it? I'm not familiar with CI but I can't find this constant: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1-stable/application/config/constants.php or https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/app/Config/Constants.php

Comment: @A.L. Please check this https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/concepts/structure.html#app

Comment: You should also define it as an integer `2`, not a string `'2'`. It's not a problem, but it is better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851883/number-format-gives-wrong-output-while-using-decimal-point-as-constatnt-for-deci#comment135483825_76851883), `DECIMAL_POINT` is a reserved constant in PHP 8.2.0+, and it has a value that you don't expect.

One solution to avoid this issue is to define your own constant and add a prefix, so that the risk of PHP adding a constant with this name in a future version is lowered:

```php
define('APP_DECIMAL_POINT', 2);
```

I didn't use `defined('APP_DECIMAL_POINT') or define('APP_DECIMAL_POINT','2');` because it's better to have an error if our code try to redefine an existing constant, than silently declaring the constant with a value that can be totally different.

Then you can use:

```php
$number = 1000000;
$amount = number_format($number, DECIMAL_POINT, '.', '');
echo $amount;
```

[Try it online on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/mGBLh)